# How to explictly state that an Entity is new (transient) in JPA?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using a Spring Data `JpaRepository`, with Hibernate as JPA provider.

Normally when working directly with Hibernate, the decision between `EntityManager#persist()` and `EntityManager#save()` is up to the programmer. With Spring Data repositories, there is only `save()`. I do not want to discuss the pros and cons here. Let us consider the following, simple base class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class PersistableObject {

    @Id
    private String id;

    public PersistableObject(){
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    // hashCode() and equals() are implemented based on equality of 'id'
}
```

Using this base class, the Spring Data repository cannot tell which Entities are "new" (have not been saved to DB yet), as the regular check for  `id == null` clearly does not work in this case, because the UUIDs are eagerly assigned to ensure the correctness of `equals()` and `hashCode()`. So what the repository seems to do is to always invoke `EntityManager#merge()` - which is clearly inefficient for transient entities.

**The question is:** how do I tell JPA (or Spring Data) that an Entity is new, such that it uses `EntityManager#persist()` instead of `#merge()` if possible?

I was thinking about something along these lines (using JPA lifecycle callbacks):

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class PersistableObject {

     @Transient
     private boolean isNew = true; // by default, treat entity as new

     @PostLoad
     private void loaded(){
         // a loaded entity is never new
         this.isNew = false;
     }

     @PostPersist
     private void saved(){
         // a saved entity is not new anymore
         this.isNew = false;
     }

     // how do I get JPA (or Spring Data) to use this method?
     public boolean isNew(){
         return this.isNew;
     }

     // all other properties, constructor, hashCode() and equals same as above

}
```

Comment: equals() and hashCode() should be based on business keys not data storage keys. UUIDs are bad primary keys too, performance-wise.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. Unfortunately it is nearly impossible to come up with a generic solution for this problem where nobody plays the "bad practice!" card. In the end it's a trade-off: I rather manage identities myself and have a clean hashCode() and equals() than having Hibernate query the database just to retrieve the next entries in the ID sequence.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe you should add @Version column:

```
@Version
private Long version
```

in the case of new entity it will be null

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly what I was looking for! Your answer lead me to this excellent article: [Don't let hibernate steal your identity](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/09/13/dont-let-hibernate-steal-your-identity.html?page=1) - which explains precisely my situation.

Answer (score 12):

I'd like to add one more remark here. Even though it only works for Spring Data and not for general JPA, I think it's worth mentioning that Spring provides the [Persistable](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Persistable.html)`<T>` interface which has two methods:

```
T getId();
boolean isNew();
```

By implementing this interface (e.g. as in the opening question post), the Spring Data JpaRepositories will ask the entity itself if it is new or not, which can be pretty handy in certain cases.